# Strange behaviour when assigning values with JRI

Tags: java, r, jri

I am facing a strange behaviour when assigning values with JRI. 
Just this little example:

```
REXP a = re.eval("a<-cbind(c(1,2))");
REXP out1 = re.eval("a[1,]"); <--- Returns a correct REXP object

re.assign("a",a);
REXP out2 = re.eval("a[1,]"); <--- Returns null (out2=null)
```

Why does it return null? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Al-tough the assign method can get REXP values as argument, R probably didn't recognize it, convert "a" into a double

```
REXP in = re.eval("a[1,]");
 double test = in.asDouble();
re.assign("test",test);
```